# Ignited Datatables get id when joining table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I was using ignited datatables plugin for Code igniter,
The problem is when join two table with this model :

```
public $table = 'user';

public function getDataTable(){
$this->load->library('datatables');
$this->datatables->select('user.username, role.name, user.id')
        ->join('role', ''.$this->table.'.role = role.id')            
        ->edit_column('id', '<button data-id="$1" id="edit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> <button data-id="$1" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>', 'id');
$this->datatables->from($this->table);

return $this->datatables->generate('json', '');
}
```

It show me the result like this :
[image]

But the edit button doesn't show me the id of user.id
edit button result (firebug)

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":
[
{"username":"admin","name":"admin","id":"<button data-id=\"id\" id=\"edit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"><\/i> Edit<\/button> <button data-id=\"id\" id=\"delete\" class=\"btn btn-danger\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"><\/i> Delete<\/button>"},
{"username":"admin2","name":"staff","id":"<button data-id=\"id\" id=\"edit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"><\/i> Edit<\/button> <button data-id=\"id\" id=\"delete\" class=\"btn btn-danger\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"><\/i>Delete<\/button>"}
],
"sColumns":"user.username,role.name,user.id"}
```

as you can see data-id="id" but i want data-id="1" or data-id="2" (user.id result from $1)

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours facing with this problem now i found the answer myself!
This problem caused by ambiguity of FK and PK so i adding alias on select query.

I change this line :

```
$this->datatables->select('user.username, role.name, user.id')
```

to

```
$this->datatables->select('user.username, role.name, user.id as uid')
```

and then change

```
->edit_column('id', '<button data-id="$1" id="edit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> <button data-id="$1" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>', 'id');
```

to

```
->edit_column('id', '<button data-id="$1" id="edit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> <button data-id="$1" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>', 'uid');
```